# Populate a database with python and Django efficiently

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

We are trying to populate a database with Python and Django with random numbers, but we have a lot of rows to go through, and it takes like 20 minutes to carry out that task.

This is our code. We have 210000 rows to go through

```
def populate(request):

    all_accounts = Account.objects.all()
    count = 0

    for account in all_accounts:
        account.avg_deal_size = round(random.randint(10, 200000), 2)
        account.save()
        print(f"Counter of accounts: {count}")
        count += 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: For this purpose you may to use factory-boy. Create `AccountFactory` and then run `create_batch(size=N)`

Comment: @a1k89 OP is modifying existing rows, factory-boy isn't really the tool for that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need any logic in `.save()`, or signals to be executed or such, just use SQL to have your RDBMS do the heavy lifting. This should execute in seconds if that.

```
from django.db import connection

def populate(request):
    with connection.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("UPDATE myapp_account SET avg_deal_size = round(10 + random() * 190000, 2)")
        (res,) = cur.fetchone()
        print(f"{res} rows affected.")
```

Comment: Will be trying it! Thank you!